# Facebook Like Button configurator not working for certain pages

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to use the Facebook Like Button Configurator to generate the Like button for a facebook page URL but it's not showing up:

Here are the steps I performed:

1. Goto https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator
2. Type in 'https://www.facebook.com/LoveJadot/' in the 'URL to Like' textfield and hit tab to move to the next field.
3. The Like button does not appear below.

It does, however, work for all other facebook pages. Our client wants to know if this is a facebook issue and if so, what's the solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is because the page is about alcohol and therefor age restricted

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution for this? Something at the client's end that we may suggest?

Comment: I have the same problem with https://www.facebook.com/gatewayhomeinspection, which clearly isn't an child-inappropriate site.

Comment: Have seen meta tag og:restrictions:age in the facebooks docs? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties/ Is there also the og:restrictions:content
, says: "Currently the only content restriction supported is for alcohol."

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is making a few changes when it comes to promoting alcohol. Many groups and campaigns are being affected by this change.

Unfortunately we can't say for now what Facebook will end up doing. And there is no way around it at the moment(at least they did not communicate one yet).